# Why it is not floating?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have got some code. And can't understand why it isn't working.

```
var cena = 0;
$.post('ajax.php?action=kosztKategorii', {kat_id: v_kat, zaCo: v_zaCo}, function(data)
        {
            cena = parseFloat(data);
            $('#'+cont_id).html(data);
        });
return cena;
```

Issue is that return value is NaN. And data i equal to "1.12" (literaly), in my div that it is putted via $('#'+cont_id).html(data) and it is displayed correctly. What is wrong with that parseFloat() function?

Comment: @neosatan It helps convince other people to actually spend their time trying to help you

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks: good point. Don't know what I was thinking writing something like that.

Comment: @SLaks: post your point to answer, ane I will accept it, cause it is exact answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.post` is **asynchronous**.
Your callback doesn't run until some time after the rest of the function finishes.

Instead, you need to return the value using a callback.